# Xamarin - Null pointer exception when trying to start Activity outside the Main Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, xamarin

I have an app and here is the first code block

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle oBundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(oBundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Layout_Main);

        FragmentTransaction oFragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsFragment oSlidingTabsFragment = new SlidingTabsFragment();

        oFragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.SampleContentFragment, oSlidingTabsFragment);

        oFragmentTransaction.Commit();
    }
```

This app has a Swiping Tab Layout and I create a custom Sliding Tab Fragment. Here  is the SlidingTabsFragment Class Code

```
public class SlidingTabsFragment : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater oLayoutInflater, ViewGroup oViewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return oLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Layout_SlidingLayoutBase, oViewGroup, false);
    }

    public override void OnViewCreated(View oView, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SlidingTabScrollView oSlidingTabScrollView = oView.FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.SlidingLayout_SlidingTabScrollView);

        ViewPager oViewPager = oView.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.SlidingLayout_ViewPager);

        oViewPager.Adapter = new TabPageAdapter();

        oSlidingTabScrollView.ViewPager = oViewPager;
    }
}
```

So on SlidingTabFragment inherits from Fragment - on create view it inflates the layout and onViewCreated it Sets Up SlidingTabScrollView, ViewPager and TabPageAdapter. Tab page adapter has a bit of code that takes care of TabItem Contents.

So here is my problem:

On of the TabItems has a listview - and I am listening for an OnClick Event. The Goal Is To Start a New Activity When I catch this event.

I get a Java.Lang.NullPointerException and here it is. I have tried adding Activity name in the Manifest File but it did not make a difference. I went through at least 10 posts about it and could not get an idea of why is not it starting it. If I catch a ButtonBackPRess and insert my snippet there it works just fine.

```
Intent oIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SignInActivity));
        StartActivity(oIntent);
```

It is this TabLayout and different classes that does not let me see a clear picture of what is going on. Why can not I start the activity fellows?

```
  Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 
at at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00068>
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:896
  at Android.Content.ContextWrapper.StartActivity (Android.Content.Intent) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.Content.ContextWrapper.cs:2895
  at MyAppName.TabLayouts..ctor (Android.Views.ViewGroup) [0x0003d] in c:\Xamarin\MyAppName\MyAppName\TabLayouts.cs:41
  at MyAppName.TabPageAdapter.InstantiateItem (Android.Views.ViewGroup,int) [0x00001] in c:\Xamarin\MyAppName\MyAppName\TabPageAdapter.cs:44
  at at Android.Support.V4.View.PagerAdapter.n_InstantiateItem_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_I (intptr,intptr,intptr,int) <IL 0x00014, 0x000ff>
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.19196691-50f4-44b8-a7cd-7a7ffc0f8179 (intptr,intptr,intptr,int) <IL 0x0001d, 0x0004f>
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at java.lang.NullPointerException
  at at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
  at at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)
  at at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
  at at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
  at at MyAppName.TabPageAdapter.n_instantiateItem(Native Method)
  at at MyAppName.TabPageAdapter.instantiateItem(TabPageAdapter.java:47)
  at at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
  at at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:987)
  at at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
  at at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
  at at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  at at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  at at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
  at at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
  at at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2533)
  at at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1350)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1547)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1234)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6465)
  at at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
  at at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
  at at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
  at at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
  at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
  at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest File

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="MyAppName.MyAppName" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="MyAppName" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"></application>
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".SignInActivity"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Completely off-topic but any reason you're prefixing all your parameters/variables except the Bundle param with "o"? :-)

Comment: The simplest answer would be - o stands for an Object. I should have prefixed the bundle parameter as well to stay consistent with the naming convention I tend to follow - just missed it when I was copying it. I had to quickly reproduce the problem without exposing the code - so I just rushed and did not notice it. ; ) Thanks to your question - I know corrected that inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code where you start activity, by I suspect the problem is with the `this` in your line:

```
Intent oIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SignInActivity));
```

I suspect you're not passing the parent Activity's context there. Try changing it so you're using the Activity in the intent, and not the context of the view/tab you're doing it from.

(Perhaps the NullPointerException is misleading because of something that Xamarin is doing internally to wrap the context.)

Comment: I do have a code in my question - under Main Activity, sir

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions you must know, while handling with fragments.

First: You can only replace fragments which has been added dynamically.

Second: You must define a "placeholder" layout, which will be your point to insert(add) and replace fragments with.

Check whether `Resource.Id.SampleContentFragment` is present in `Resource.Layout.Layout_Main` 
Similarly for `SlidingTabsFragment`

Hope this was helpful.